# Passing widget options to external script

Tags: widgets, options, wp-localize-script

I am trying to pass some widget options to an external script using `wp_localize_script`. I know how to pass the variables and how to use them within the script, but how do I extract the widget options to pass them as an array to the script? Here is what I have currently:

```
class WidgetName extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {

        // load plugin text domain
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'widget_textdomain' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'register_widget_scripts' ) );

    }

    // This is what i'm having a problem with
    public function register_widget_scripts() {
        $options = get_option('widget-name');
        wp_localize_script('handle', 'obj-name', $options);

    }
    // The rest of the widget code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_settings()` member function:

```
public function register_widget_scripts() {
    $options = $this->get_settings();
    wp_localize_script( 'widget-name', 'obj-name', $options );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @bungeshea. Any idea why this doesn't work for me?